# Typescript d3(Power BI)

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, powerbi

How can I create d3.axis() or any other d3 object in typescript when creating Power BI custom visual and make it show up on screen?

Answer (score 0):

IF use your js code to create axis in d3 typescript will work

you can check demo git on

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals